# Android Bitmap return null from other class

Tags: android

I try to create a class that get image and cache it at memory but it does not return value to my list adapter class. When I debug, I can see the bitmap value in GetImagesBitmap but after return to ListTestAdapter, the value is null. Can anyone guide me please. Thanks.

This is my GetImagesBitmap class which will return value to ListTestAdapter

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.net.URL;


public class GetImagesBitmap extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final String TAG = "MY_MESSAGE";
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private String url;

    public GetImagesBitmap() {
    }

    public GetImagesBitmap(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap bitmap1 = (Bitmap) ImageCache.getInstance().getLru().get(url);
        if (bitmap == null) {
            try {
                URL newurl = new URL(url);
                bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(newurl.openConnection().getInputStream());
                ImageCache.getInstance().getLru().put(url, bitmap1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
            }
        }

        return bitmap1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap2) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap2;
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

ListTestAdapter.java

```
package com.example.chaifs.test.adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

import com.example.chaifs.test.R;
import com.example.chaifs.test.controller.GetImagesBitmap;
import com.example.chaifs.test.model.*;

import java.util.List;

public class ListTestAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private final String TAG = "MY_MESSAGE";
    private List<Test> mItems;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ListTestAdapter(Context context, List<Test> listTest) {
        this.setItems(listTest);
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Test getItem(int position) {
        return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().get(position) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return (getItems() != null && !getItems().isEmpty()) ? getItems().get(position).getId() : position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        View v = convertView;
        if (v == null) {
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_test, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imgView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            holder.txtId = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
            holder.button1 = (ToggleButton) v.findViewById(R.id.tgl_status);
            holder.button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ((ListView) parent).performItemClick(v, position, 0);
                }
            });
            v.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        }

        // fill row data
        Test currentItem = getItem(position);
        if (currentItem != null) {
            holder.txtId.setText(currentItem.getId().toString());
            holder.button1.setChecked(currentItem.getBookmarkStatus().equals("true") ? true : false);

            //this part which cannot get the bitmap return value
            GetImagesBitmap getImagesBitmap = new GetImagesBitmap(currentItem.getImageURL());
            getImagesBitmap.execute();
            Bitmap bitmap = getImagesBitmap.getBitmap();
            Log.e(TAG, "size of bitmap" + String.valueOf(bitmap.getByteCount()));
            holder.imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
        return v;
    }

    public List<Test> getItems() {
        return mItems;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Test> mItems) {
        this.mItems = mItems;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imgView;
        TextView txtId;
        ToggleButton button1;

    }

}
```

Comment: if are loading image from internet then use picasso library.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're not waiting for the AysncTask to complete. Here's what you have

```
//this part which cannot get the bitmap return value
GetImagesBitmap getImagesBitmap = new GetImagesBitmap(currentItem.getImageURL());
getImagesBitmap.execute();
Bitmap bitmap = getImagesBitmap.getBitmap();
```

But the execute() call is non-blocking so it returns immediately which means that your image hasn't been fetched yet.

Comment: Searched half hour and did not found solution yet. So how can I wait the AysncTask to complete? Can you help me. Thanks.

Comment: It's a surprisingly difficult problem. I'd recommend using a library like Picasso.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are using to fetch bitmap from server is slightly wrong.

```
        //this part which cannot get the bitmap return value
        GetImagesBitmap getImagesBitmap = new GetImagesBitmap(currentItem.getImageURL());
        getImagesBitmap.execute();
        Bitmap bitmap = getImagesBitmap.getBitmap();
        Log.e(TAG, "size of bitmap" + String.valueOf(bitmap.getByteCount()));
        holder.imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Okay here you are making a network call to fetch a bitmap from server, and in next line you are asking for bitmap. Asynchtask runs on a different thread, so better to use callback so that whenever your download will be completed it will just inform you through callbacks.